# Iptables rules doesn't work as expected

Tags: iptables, firewall

1. I need to block access to my server from the outside of my private network.
2. I need to allow pings from my server out only to my private network and answer pings initiated from my private network as well.

But with these rules I have set, it does not work as it blocks me from pinging and my server does not answer pings initiated from my private network.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -s 0/0 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT

iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 0/0 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -j REJECT
```

Comment: If you have rules in two directions, you have to contemplate all the rules in the two directions. You may also to use more the ESTABLISHED and RELATED at the top of your INPUT and OUTPUT queue. Try to translate what you ask to rules.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using DROP instead of REJECT.

Chains have a policy that says what should happen to packets that doesn't match any rule, use that instead of a final rule.

Those rules won't let SSH work, as you only mention it in the INPUT chain, and traffic flows both ways.

The kernel's connection tracking is good enough, that I would recommend just having '-m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT' rules in both INPUT and OUTPUT. Then you only need to consider who initiates the connections when adding new rules.

Comment: I have tried what you said but I have got an error "Multiple -S flags are not allowed", here is the rules what I wrote :  

> iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j DROP



> iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -s 0/0 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -m state -state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT


> iptables -A INPUT -j DROP



> iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 0/0 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT



> iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP

Comment: It's been 16 days! It's way too much work for me to recall what you did if you're going to take that long to react.The rules are completely unreadable in a comment. If you get an error about multiple s-flags, it sounds like you have even thought about the rules you've made. Find and read some documentation